# Default connect command for mongoDB cluster throws "Multiple text records now allowed"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am using the following command, provided on the mongoDB portal to connect to the cluster using MongoDB Compass:`mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@clusterX.random.mongodb.net/test`

For mongo shell, I am using the following command:
`mongosh "mongodb+srv://clusterX.random.mongodb.net/test" --apiVersion 1 --username user --password password`

For mongo shell I am getting the following error:`Connecting to: mongodb+srv://<credentials>@clusterX.random.mongodb.net/test?appName=mongosh+1.6.1 Error: Multiple text records not allowed`

In both the cases, the common error is Multiple text records not allowed and I cannot figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I think you can skip `--apiVersion 1`. You can use the same connection string for `mongosh` as you use for compass, should work in the same way.

Comment: Even after skipping --apiVersion, I am facing the same error.
In compass as well, with the provided URI, the error is still the same.

Comment: If you [replace `clusterX.random.mongodb.net` with the actual host name at dnschecker.org](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=clusterX.random.mongodb.net&rtype=TXT&dns=google), do you see more than one TXT record?

Comment: I can see the following text records for the actual DNS for my cluster: `authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-dbtlv0-shard-0` @rickhg12hs

Comment: Perhaps your computer or ISP has some DNS issue.  If you follow the advice of using a different connection string as shown in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9489#issuecomment-730623013), can you connect successfully then?